# Cordova vibrate is not working

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I'm running Cordova on Android and this is my config files.

config.xml

```
<feature name="Vibration">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.vibration.Vibration" />
</feature>
<feature name="Media">
    <plugin name="Media" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler" />
</feature>
<feature name="Notification">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification" />
</feature>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

my js

```
navigator.vibrate(1000);
```

I use normal jQuery (Not jQueryMobile) to run with cordova.
Vibration plugin as already installed by command line from this page [(plugin git)](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-vibration/blob/master/doc/index.md).

But vibration is not working.

Answer (score 16):

I know this is an old thread, but, when testing on a device, be sure that the device is un-muted. Many (most) devices will "mute" the vibration as well as the audio. If you are debugging in the browser, you should see 'Vibrating for 1000ms.' in the console, which tells you the plugin is working (obviously you can't vibrate your computer). But, again, when testing on a device, be sure it's not on mute.

Comment: I meant to make a similar post here, as that was my issue back in Febuary. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Same issue. I had my `Media` volume up but `System` volume was muted (which I didn't realize). Make sure that your System volume is on `Vibrate` or `Sound` (you can use the `Volume` icon from the System UI when you drag down on the top of your phone).

Answer (score 1):

- feature lines in config.xml are only usefull if you use phonegap build, you don't need it if you build using the CLI
- you should not update androidmanifest directly, it's updated when you install the plugin.
- maybe try `navigator.notification.vibrate(1000)`? (it's supposed to be deprecated but it's working for me)

Comment: I'm using Cordova not Phonegap.
All other feature lines work fine such as media.

Comment: I don't say the feature lines work or don't work, just that they're useless and you should not add them unless if you use phonegap BUILD. The way it works is that cordova cli will automatically add the feature lines in the platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml file when you add plugins using the command `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.vibration` and then build the android platform.

Comment: I'm having this problem too, vibrate doesn't work. :/ Besides adding the plugin and calling the navigator.vibrate() call, is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: @TheMintyMate: See my possible solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/36629897/3261560

Answer (score 0):

You need to add permission (android.permission.VIBRATE).