# Cordova vibrate plugin is not working in ios

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have implemented an app and I need a vibrate function to invoke on a button click in `angularjs`. It works fine on `android`, but on `iOS` it says that `navigator` is `undefined`.

I have used the below plugin for the vibrate function
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-vibration

Is there any workaround I need to do get it work on iOS?

Comment: Try to remove and re-add the plugin?!

Comment: Did you have any luck?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the device is muted? I had this issue where everything was logging correctly but my system volume was off. [This post on Android solved it for me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596228/cordova-vibrate-is-not-working/36629897#36629897) In case your phone has different types of volumes (media, call, etc), un-muting `System` volume is what solved my trouble.

> be sure that the device is un-muted. Many (most) devices will "mute" the vibration as well as the audio.